# ImportError : Cannot import name

Tags: python, ubuntu, qt5, lib, qtcore

```
File "</home/user/paparazzi/sw/supervision/python/paparazzicenter.py", line 8, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtCore import PyQt5_QtCore
ImportError: cannot import name 'PyQt5_QtCore' from 'PyQt5.QtCore' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so)
```

Is there any solution in this error

Comment: I don't believe `PyQt5_QtCore` exists, so this seems to be a simple error on your part --  you're trying to import the wrong thing.  Where did you get the name `PyQt5_QtCore`?  Did you copy it from some example?

Comment: Did you mean to write `import PyQt5.QtCore as PyQt5_QtCore`?

Comment: Yes. I try a lot of solution but still don't get the correct one

Comment: When I'm using QtCore still get the same error.

Comment: What are you trying to import? Because if you are trying to import QtCore then you should use `from PyQt5 import QtCore`.

Comment: This doesn't exist. You can see all `PyQt5.QtCore` Classes here: https://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/PyQt5/QtCore.html